# Which cultures worship boars?

Tags: comparative, hindu, mythohistory, animals, worship

I'm searching for a list of cultures/regions which worshiped/revered boars.

I only know of Hinduism of the Indian Subcontinent, where an avatar of Lord Vishnu, [Varaha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varaha) is worshiped.

Further, I'm only aware of the excavations of idols of Varaha in the Indian subcontinent, so if there are any in other regions (even if pertaining to Hinduism), I'd like to know about that too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_boar#In_culture  - could this be a  starting point for composing an answer to your question?

Comment: Didn't Persians have some proto-zodiac? Several animals in a circle and one of them was a boar. But I could be very wrong.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Boars_in_heraldry

Answer (score 2):

Boars have been revered and worshiped by many cultures and regions throughout history. In ancient Greece, the wild boar was associated with the goddess Artemis, who was often depicted with a boar at her side. In Japanese mythology, the boar is associated with the Shinto god Inari, who is the patron of agriculture, fertility, and prosperity. In Celtic mythology, the boar was associated with the warrior god Moccus. Additionally, boars have been revered by many indigenous cultures around the world, including some Native American tribes and Pacific Island cultures.